# Is is possible to deserialize JSON input in an object of non annotated class?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm wondering if it's possible to deserialize a JSON String into a class object that has no annotation.

Let's say I don't have a JSON schema and I can't generate pojo classes but I already have classes without annotations. Is there a way for a deserializer to automatically detect class attributes and subclasses attributes?

I've been looking for solutions on the Internet, but all the solutions concern classes where there are no subclasses as attributes. In my case I have a complex class structure, the attribute names are also the same or similar to the element names in the JSON string.

I also tried to generate classes based on my JSON string. I did this with [jsonschema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), but the problem is that my pojo classes only contain elements that are listed in the JSON string, so they are not fully generated. Without the JSON scheme I cannot generate them.

Comment: So have you tried to deserialize without annotations? It should be possible if field names match. Please provide an example of a real case.

Comment: No, they don't match and that is my problem. Just some of them match. Another problem: classes included in the class that I want to deserialize don't have all attributes that match to child fields of the JSON input. :/

Comment: This is the class without Annotations: 
https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/api/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/GHResponse.java

@pirho, for example, in my JSON input, I have a field called "hints" but there is no attribute with that identifier inside this class but "hintsMap" and that is why I get an error that this field can't be referenced to any of the attributes in the class.

Comment: While links to complete code are sometimes useful it is most often more useful to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Guess that mixin is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can serialize/deserialize types without Jackson annotation. This is clearly demonstrated in the [tutorial](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind):

```java
public class MyValue {
  public String name;
  public int age;
  // NOTE: if using getters/setters, can keep fields `protected` or `private`
}
```

And:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyValue value = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"Bob\", \"age\":13}", MyValue.class);
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myResultObject);
```

If you need to customize the serialization of types without annotation (either because you do not control these classes or because you do not want to pollute them with Jackson annotations or for any other reason), use [mixins](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations). With it, you define a type having the same property names as the type you want to serialize/deserialize and define annotation there. Then you instruct Jackson to (de-)serialize an object, but using configuration from the mixin:

```java
public class CannotModify {
  String name;
  Date birthdate;
}

public class MixIn {
  @JsonFormat(...)
  Date birthdate;
}

objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(CannotModify.class, MixIn.class);
// now this ObjectMapper will use the format specified in the MixIn
// to format the birthdate field of CannotModify
```

Checkout the full documentation for other interesting features.

---

Now if property names do not match, you use the `@JsonProperty` and give it the name of the JSON property. So, continuing the example above, say that the JSON you want to (de-)serialize to `CannotModify` is as follows:

```json
{
  "onoma": "...",
  "birth_date": "..."
}
```

Just annotate the mixin as:

```java
public class MixIn {
  @JsonProperty("onoma")
  String name;

  @JsonProperty("birth_date")
  @JsonFormat(...)
  Date birthdate;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, this is possible if attributes inside the class match the field names inside JSON input. In my case, just some of them match, and some are similar, but they don't match. Hence this is the case, field values (which names don't match) can't be found in the class attributes.

Comment: In this case use `@JsonProperty` on the mixin, see edit. And Jackson can deal with more complex scenaria in more complex ways, but without a concrete example, this is out of context for the question.